# Is it possible to reset Accessibility Application that have been changed due to learning how things work?

Tags: macos, settings, accessibility

Is it possible to reset Accessibility Application? I want to keep learning about it but want to make sure I can get it back to settings that are not user configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider enabling the Guest account (System Preferences > Users & Groups) and switching to that user to test with.

The Guest account can access the Accessibility settings in System Preferences, and when you logout of the Guest account all the changes are deleted.